# Constructor That Crashes Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

The code

```
Army.Add(new PigSquad("The Old Guard", 10, 4));
```

Where `Army` is a `List<Unit>` and `Pigsquad` is defined as

```
public class PigSquad : Unit
{
    public override bool Dead { get; set; }
    public override string Name { get; set;}
    public override int Strength { get; set; }
    public override int Age { get { return Age; } set { Age = value; Strength += 20 - Age; if (Age > 20) { Dead = true; } } }
    public override int Veterancy { get; set; }
    public PigSquad()
    {

    }
    public PigSquad(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public PigSquad(string Name, int Strength)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Strength = Strength;
    }
    public PigSquad(string Name, int Strength, int Age)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Strength = Strength;
        this.Age = Age;
    }
}
```

Crashes the Unity Editor when ran. I have no idea why this is. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the Unit class look like? Is it derived from MonoBehavior? Where is the addition to the list called?

Comment: The setter and getter for the `Age` property cause infinite recursion, essentially locking up the thread (or whole program ) that tries to set/get this property. Use a backing field (call it `private int _age;`, for example) in conjunction with the `Age` property.

Comment: Thank You!!! I have spent literally hours trying to fix this.

Comment: FYI: Small correction to my former comment due to having a brain fart: While the infinite recursion would lock up the thread setting/getting the Age property, it would eventually (and rather quickly, actually) cause a StackOverflowException.

Comment: I had also been getting a stack overflow exception when I would make it run, that would explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public override int Age { get { return Age; } set { Age = value; Strength += 20 - Age; if (Age > 20) { Dead = true; } } }
```

should be

```
private int _Age; //maybe make this in your UNIT object as well and that way you do not need it in your child.
public override int Age { get { return _Age; } set { _Age = value; Strength += 20 - _Age; if (Age > 20) { Dead = true; } } }
```